Why is PowerBI Query giving an Error for Sumx?
I am in the DAX trying to create an equation for expenses. My equation is Expenses=('Data',[hours][employee salary][other fees]. I have confirmed the name of the data table and column name but I am still getting a syntax error. Any help would be appreciated.

Something like this maybe? I'm assuming your hourly rate is a column in the DimEmployee table
Expenses=SUMX('Data',
   [hours] * RELATED('DimEmployee'[Hourly Rate])
)

